# Defining operator norm as the spectral norm of its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite, quantum-information, spectral-norm

Suppose $T$ maps between symmetric positive definite $d$-by-$d$ matrices $X,Y$ as follows:

$$\operatorname{vec}(Y)=M\operatorname{vec}(X)$$

$M$ is a symmetric positive definite $d^2$-by-$d^2$ matrix. Suppose we define norm $\|T\|_*$ to be the spectral norm of $M$, is there another name for $\|\cdot\|_*$?

This norm comes up indirectly in statistics, and I was curious to find another representation for it. A related example uses Russo-Dye to give a simple expression for induced trace norm $\|T\|_1$, page 167 of Theory of Quantum Information [textbook](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/TQI.pdf)

Comment: I believe that this is called the "induced $2$-norm" in Watrous's terminology.

Comment: @BenGrossmann would it be fair to call this the "spectral radius of T, lower bound on every norm of T"?

Comment: One could say that it is the **spectral norm** of $T$, which is a lower bound on every **unitarily invariant** norm defined for operators over a $d^2$ dimensional space. It is not necessarily equal to the spectral radius of $T$ because $T$ is not necessarily a self-adjoint transformation.